# Confused by error 424

Tags: excel, vba

I'm fairly new to VBA and have had some issues with a script I've been tasked to write. What it's supposed to do is to use the semicolon-spaced data in a single cell (the data contains names and numbers inside brackets) and find the names with the biggest numbers then separate that into different cells.

To take out the numbers from string I'm using the custom function ExtractNumber developed by ozgrid: http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/ExtractNum.htm

I keep getting error 424 while trying to call that function, in this part of my code:

```
For i = 0 To a
    stored(i) = ExtractNumber((Full(i)))
Next i
```

From what I understand, this error pops up when variables are defined improperly or not defined at all. I double-checked all my variables and also tried running the code without "option explicit", but no luck. It might be something really obvious that's the issue here, but I can't seem for the life of me to find it!

Could anyone have any suggestions on what to do to avoid this error? Here is my full code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Divide()

Dim txt As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim Full As Variant
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer
Dim stored() As Integer

txt = (CStr(ActiveCell.Value))
Full = Split(txt, ";")
a = UBound(Full)
b = a - 1

ReDim stored(b)

For i = 0 To a
    stored(i) = ExtractNumber((Full(i)))
Next i

Dim primary_index As Integer
Dim primary_no As Integer
Dim primary_name As String
primary_index = Application.Match(Application.Max(stored), stored, 0)
primary_no = stored(primary_index)
primary_name = Full(primary_index)
stored(primary_index) = 0

If UBound(stored) > 1 Then
    Dim secondary_index As Integer
    Dim secondary_no As Integer
    Dim secondary_name As String
    secondary_index = Application.Match(Application.Max(stored), stored, 0)
    secondary_no = stored(secondary_index)
    secondary_name = Full(secondary_index)
End If

For i = 0 To 6
    ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Offset(0, 1).Insert
Next i

If UBound(stored) > 2 Then
    Dim names() As String
    ReDim names(0 To a)
    For j = 0 To a
        If Not (j = primary_index Or j = secondary_index) Then
            names(j) = Full(j)
        End If
    Next j

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = primary_name
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = primary_no
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = secondary_name
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = secondary_no
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value = names
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Value = (ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Value - primary_no             - secondary_no)

ElseIf UBound(stored) = 2 Then
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = primary_name
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = primary_no
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = secondary_name
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = secondary_no
End

Else
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = primary_name
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = primary_no
End

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: First parameter of `ExtractNumber` expects a `Range`. You are passing a `String`.

Answer (score 0):

The function wants a range:

```
Function ExtractNumber(rCell As Range,
```

but you pass a string, in this case because of how that function works you can  simply change the function to:

```
ExtractNumber(rCell As String,
```

---

The confusing error you get is because you have an extra pair of parentheses around the variable you pass:

`ExtractNumber((Full(i)))`

This has the effect of forcing it to be passed ByVal instead of ByRef which is not valid for an object variable (`rCell`) and causes the 424 error you see.

If you change to `ExtractNumber(Full(i))` you will get a more obvious type-mismatch error for the reason explained above.

Comment: Thank you very much for the tip, @alex-k ! I did as you suggested, sadly now I have another error which pops up at the last part of ExtractNumber: ExtractNumber = CInt(lNum) is the part that bugs out. I tried defining this variable in several different ways as well as removing the forced switch to int. It keeps saying 'type mismatch'.. Could I trouble you to look at the code once more, please?